# Casting objects from character buffer in c

Tags: c, casting

Can anyone explain why this code wont compile?

**main.c**

```
typedef struct ext2_group_desc
{
    unsigned long bg_block_bitmap;  /* Blocks bitmap block */
    unsigned long bg_inode_bitmap;  /* Inodes bitmap block */
    unsigned long bg_inode_table;       /* Inodes table block */
    unsigned int bg_free_blocks_count;  /* Free blocks count */
    unsigned int bg_free_inodes_count;  /* Free inodes count */
    unsigned int bg_used_dirs_count;    /* Directories count */
    unsigned int bg_pad;
    unsigned long bg_reserved[3];
} group_desc;

int main() {
    char buf[1024];
    group_desc gd;

    gd = (group_desc) buf;

    return(0);
}
```

**Terminal**

```
$ bcc -ansi -c test.c
test.c:7.26: error: need scalar or pointer or void
test.c:7.26: error: assignment to/from struct/union of a different type
$
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? What is `ext2_group_desc`. Your code tries to tell the compiler,*Treat an character array as same as `ext2_group_desc`*, Do you think it is true?

Comment: In my actual code, I read a block of the hard drive into this `char buf` and then try to cast it onto a group descriptor struct (not 1024 bytes).

Answer (score 4):

You are missing some definition for `ext2_group_desc` (maybe in some included file?). I am guessing it is some `struct`. Then you might code

```
   gd = *(ext2_group_desc*) buf;
```

if you want to copy the memory at `buf` into the `gd` structure.

Please read a good book on C programming. Learning C takes many days of work.

Also enable all the warnings in your compiler.

Comment: That doesn't work either, I can use it as a pointer `(ext2_group_desc *) buf`, but the question was why doesn't mine compile. I know it's broken, this site has the goal of telling me why. I added the supplied struct, sorry, I figured people who "knew C" would assume that it was a struct.

Comment: Read some good C programming book.

Comment: Can you tell me why this question is vague? In English it seems quite reasonable to ask WHY this does not compile... Maybe I did read a book and now I am trying stuff out, but I've reached a point and don't know why it doesn't work.